# CherryPy: 405 Method Not Allowed Specified method is invalid for this resource

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm building my first web app with authentication in cherrypy: the auth piece works, but after the login I get the error `405 Method Not Allowed
Specified method is invalid for this resource`. Any idea on how to overcome it?

Thanks in advance!

```
from cherrypy.lib import auth_digest
import cherrypy

USERS = {'jon': 'secret'}

config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8,
    'log.screen'         : True
  },
  '/' : {
    # HTTP verb dispatcher
    'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
    # JSON response
    'tools.json_out.on' : True,
    # Digest Auth
    'tools.auth_digest.on'      : True,
    'tools.auth_digest.realm'   : 'walledgarden',
    'tools.auth_digest.get_ha1' : auth_digest.get_ha1_dict_plain(USERS),
    'tools.auth_digest.key'     : 'generate_something_random',
  }
}

class HelloWorld():
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

#cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), config=None) #this works
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), config=config) #this is broken
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `cyraxjoe` pointers I figured it out:

```
from cherrypy.lib import auth_digest
import cherrypy

USERS = {'jon': 'secret'}

config = {'/': {'tools.auth_digest.on': True,
               'tools.auth_digest.realm': 'walledgarden',
               'tools.auth_digest.get_ha1': auth_digest.get_ha1_dict_plain(USERS),
               'tools.auth_digest.key': 'generate_something_random',
}}

class HelloWorld():
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

#cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), config=None) #this works -- NO AUTHENTICATION
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), config=config) #WORKS WITH AUTHENTICATION
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `MethodDispacher` which maps the HTTP methods as *methods* of the *exposed* class, in this case your `index` method should be called `GET`.

```
@cherrypy.expose
class HelloWorld():

    def GET(self):
        return "Hello World!"
```

If you are using a version of python that doesn't support class decorators, then use:

```
class HelloWorld():
    exposed = True

    def GET(self):
        return "Hello World!"
```

Basically, with the `MethodDispatcher` you expose *resources* (objects) that has methods matching the HTTP method, like `GET` - > `def GET(self)` or `POST` -> `def POST(self)`.

You might find this post informative: https://blog.joel.mx/posts/cherrypy-101-method-dispatcher

Comment: Thank you! What would be then the alternative to MethodDispatcher? I looked the configuration documentation but I couldn't get a clear example -- http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/config.html